# I'm missing something about responsive design

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

There seems to be a missing link in my understanding of making responsive websites. I'm using CSS media query to make navbar responsive when screen size changes.

When I reduce the size of the chrome window, the navbar changes from row to column as I want, but when I click the toggle device button in the inspector to change to mobile, everything goes back to row and it's not responsive anymore. I thought setting the CSS rules to change the layout on screen size change would account for mobile. What am I missing?

This is what it looks like full size
[image]

This is what it looks like with chrome reduced
[image: This is what it looks like with chrome reduced]

This is what it looks like on mobile
[image: This is what it looks like on mobile]

codepen: https://codepen.io/PrinceCorwin/pen/QWKdjZq

My CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: transparent;

  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
#welcome-section {
  background-image: url("https://bridgetales.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/gallery-background.png");

  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
}

#navbar a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #0ae1e9;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#welcome-text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
}
#welcome-head {
  font-family: "Bubbler One", sans-serif;
  font-size: 58px;
  color: #0ae1e9;
}
#welcome-greet {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Bubbler One", sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  #welcome-head {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  #welcome-greet {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  #navbar a {
    font-size: 0.7em;
  }
  #navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #welcome-text {
    padding-top: 50%;
  }
}
```

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>The Gallery - Steve Amalfitano</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bubbler+One&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <nav id="navbar">
        <a href="">WEB APPS</a>
        <a href="">WOODWORKING</a>
        <a href="webdev.html">WEB DESIGN</a>
      </nav>
      <div id="welcome-section">
        <div id="welcome-text">
          <div id="welcome-head">STEVE CORWIN AMALFITANO</div>
          <div id="welcome-greet">THE GALLERY</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `viewport` meta tag is missing. Google: `responsive meta tag`

Comment: Thank you, jeprubio. I had that in the beginning. Don't know how it got deleted. It was driving me crazy. Sometimes it just takes another set of eyes. Fixed the navbar issue. Now I just have to worry about the text being responsive. Thanks again

Comment: As @jeprubio suggested, try adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> in the head section